# player immortality for 5 seconds when teleporting to Bukkit?

Tags: java, bukkit

Good evening, I want to make a plugin that, when the player reaches the Y == 0.0 coordinate, teleports him to another world.

I have code like this now:

```
public class main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable() {
        this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void tp(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        Location loc = p.getLocation();
        double y = loc.getY();
        double X = 132.0;
        double Y = 70.0;
        double Z = 256.0;
        if(y <= 0.0) {
            p.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), X, Y, Z));
        }
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamageEvent(final EntityDamageEvent e) {
        Entity p1 = e.getEntity();
        Location loc = p1.getLocation();
        Player p = (Player) p1;
        double X = loc.getX();
        double Y = loc.getY();
        double Z = loc.getZ();
        DamageCause a = e.getCause();
        
        if (e.getCause() == DamageCause.FALL) {
            e.setCancelled(true);
            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, () -> {e.setCancelled(false);;}, 20L * 5);
        }
    }
}
```

How can all this be connected and so that immortality is activated precisely after teleportation, and not after a fall?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to store the player's UUID into a list when they are teleported and spawn a task to remove them from that list to fire when you want their fall immunity to end.

Like so:

```java
    private final ArrayList<UUID> fallDamageImmune = new ArrayList<>();

    ...

    @EventHandler
    public void tp(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        if(p.getLocation().getY() > 0)
            return;
        double X = 132.0;
        double Y = 70.0;
        double Z = 256.0;
        p.teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), X, Y, Z));
        fallDamageImmune.add(p.getUniqueId());
        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(this, () -> fallDamageImmune.remove(p.getUniqueId()), 100L);
    }
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamageEvent(EntityDamageEvent e) {
        if (e.getCause() == DamageCause.FALL && e.getEntity() instanceof Player && fallDamageImmune.contains(e.getEntity().getUniqueId()))
            e.setCancelled(true);
    }
```

Just an observation but you don't check what world the player is currently in so when they are already in `world`, if they go to or beyond Y0, they'll be teleported again.